# How can I write a procedure in prolog that tags each element in a list, associating a number with it

Tags: prolog

The result is a list of `tag(N, X)` structures, where N has values 1,2,3,. . . and X represents a list element. For example

```
?- tagit([wibble,33,junk,phew],L).
 L = [tag(1, wibble), tag(2, 33), tag(3, junk), tag(4, phew)]
```

I'm new to Prolog and need to complete this please.

Comment: Looks like we have some harsh users here. Was stuck somewhere so couldn't respond @WillNess.. let me try the code. Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know what *list* is?

```
list(X):- X=[].
```

`[]` is a list.

```
list(X):- X=[A|B], list(B).
```

`[A|B]` is a list if `B` is a list.

What is a *taglist*?

```
taglist(Y):- Y=[].
```

`[]` is a taglist.

```
taglist(Y):- Y=[C|D], C=tag(N,V), taglist(D).
```

`[C|D]` is a taglist if `C=tag(N,V)` with *some* `N` and `V`, and `D` is a taglist.

Can we put the two together, smashing them into one? Yes, we can:

```
taglist2(X,Y):- X=[], Y=[].
taglist2(X,Y):- X=[A|B], Y=[C|D], ...., taglist2(B,D).
```

What is `A`? What is `V`?

What is `N`? It is a number. First number is 1:

```
number(N,One):- N is One.
```

Next number is found from a previous one, as

```
number(N,Prev):- Next is Prev + 1, number(N,Next).
```

Can we smash the three of them together? Yes, we can. Try it, it's fun.

Comment: `taglist2(X,Y):- X=[], Y=[].
taglist2(X,Y):- X=[A|B], Y=[C|D], taglist2(B,D).
:- taglist2([S, T],[W, X]).`

This is what I tried. It returns a single array with the two being combined. What I want is duplexes to be returned. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: yes, there's a `....` there; it should be replaced by some real code, not just omitted. (and then the numbers should be counted up, too). as for "duplexes",  I don't understand you, and it looks different from your question. don't change the question; ask a new one if you have it.

Comment: Well..it's not a new question...But I'm too new to prolog. I think I should get back to basics once. Thanks :)

Comment: you can try writing some actual code, then post a question about *it*. Be sure to include the code, the testing call, expected output and actual output/error messages that you get, when you do post it. otherwise, the question is a bad match for SO, and can get downvoted and closed. If you ask more than a few badly received questions, the site might automatically decide to ban you from asking new questions on SO, so beware. But if your Q. contains code/output/&c and is specific (not vague, or "give me codez", &c), then it should be OK.